# Nginx return "500 Internal Server Error" after config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am config `Nginx` for the first time, I remove `default` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, then add a simple config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /root/ruby_workspace/blog/;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

`/root/ruby_workspace/blog/` is the root path of my ruby project, I config the root path in `config/routes.rb`:`root 'static_pages#home'`. This config file return `500 Internal Server Error`

How can I config to get the homepage?

Comment: As far as i remember, you should point `root` to the public folder `root /root/ruby_workspace/blog/public;`

Comment: but, I tried `/root/ruby_workspace/blog/public;` too, this doesn't work.

Comment: check the nginx error log, and the rails log